# How to validate password with authlogic and jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, authlogic

I use the jQuery Validation plugin for validation using `remote: "/valid_password.json"` to check on the server if the submitted password is the right one. The problem is that on the server the password is encrypted (using Authlogic), so when I compare the password parameter with the stored password, they are not the same. How can I validate the password using the JQuery Validation plugin?

Here is the code in the controller:

```
def valid_password
    username = params[:user_session][:username]
    password = params[:user_session][:password]
    @user = User.find_by_username(username)
    if @user.password == password
      @password_ok = true
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @password_ok ? "true" : "false"}
    end
end
```

Edit: After searching  and reading, I have tried this: (still with no success)

```
def valid_password
    username = params[:username]
    password = params[:user_session][:password]
    @user = User.find_by_username(username)
    puts "TEST" + @user.crypted_password
    @password = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512.encrypt(password)
    puts "TEST"  + @password
    if @password == @user.crypted_password
      @password_ok = true
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @password_ok ? "true" : "false"}
    end
end
```

The two `puts` methods give different results. I think I should be using the stored password_salt to get the encryption right, but I don't know how. Originally I used the wrong parameter for "username", but now that is fixed.

Comment: Why don't you try encrypting the password you've sent with AuthLogic and then compare the encrypted versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it works!

I had to add the password_salt to the password before encrypting:

```
def valid_password
  username = params[:username]
  password = params[:user_session][:password]
  @user = User.find_by_username(username)
  password = "#{password}#{@user.password_salt}"
  @password = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512.encrypt(password)
  if @password == @user.crypted_password
    @password_ok = true
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @password_ok ? "true" : "false"}
  end
end
```